# Not displaying values from an array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, oop, foreach

I have a form that has this code in it, so I can echo the errors as I check the fields from a class:

```
<?php if( isset($_POST['send'])){     
        $new_user = new Register();
        $new_user->check_required_fields($_POST);
        $new_user->display_errors();
    } 

?>
```

and the class is:

```
<?php
    class Register extends Database
    {
        public $fname;
        public $lname;
        public $uname;
        public $email;
        public $pass1;
        public $pass2;
        public $year;
        public $month;
        public $day;
        public $required_array;
        public $error;
        public $errors = array();

        public function check_required_fields($required_array)
        {
             if(in_array('', $required_array)) {
                 $errors[] = "One or more fields are missing";
                 //var_dump($errors);
             }
             else
             { 
                 $errors[] = "All fields are ok";
                 $this->fname = $required_array['fname'];
                 $this->lname = $required_array['lname'];
                 $this->uname = $required_array['lname'];
                 $this->email = $required_array['email'];
                 $this->pass1 = $required_array['pass1'];
                 $this->pass2 = $required_array['pass2'];
                 $this->year = $required_array['year'];
                 $this->month = $required_array['month'];
                 $this->day = $required_array['day'];
             }

         }


         public function display_errors ($errors)
         {
             foreach ($errors as $error){
                 echo $error;
             }

         }
```

For some reason it will not display the $errors array and I am not sure why? I would be greatful for any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public function display_errors ($errors)
 {
     foreach($errors as $error){
            echo $error;
        }

 }
```

the "$errors" you use in the foreach statement is the one in the function display_errors's parameter list, and when you invoke the function, you didn't give any parameter, so this variable would be empty

you should use $this->errors in the foreach statement

Comment: @Josh At first glance I thought these were C-pointers. Creepy.

Comment: @Stanislav I suppose it would point to the pointer, but then what would the right side do?

Comment: bug fixed, sorry this is my fist post here :)

Comment: @Josh It would do horrible, horrible things ;-) (Nothing really, just a compile error.)

Answer (score 5):

Try using

```
$this->errors
```

in both check_required_fields and display_errors.

Comment: That, and get rid off `$errors` in `display_errors` argument: `public function display_errors()`